# Transfer website security certificate from Windows IIS to Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, certificate

I was following the directions from this site (https://www.sslshopper.com/move-or-copy-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-windows-server-to-an-apache-server.html) to migrate my GoDaddy.com certificate from a Windows Server 2003 machine to a server Running Debian & Apache (v 2.4.10).
I converted the .pfx file to a .txt and opened it to extract the Private Key and certificate.
But, my file has three certificates, not just the one in the tutorial.
So, which section is my SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile, or SSLCertificateChainFile?
I tried adding the top portion as my Private key, and the 2nd section as my Certificate, but in Chrome I get a 'NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID'message when navigating to my site.
Any help would appreciated.

```
Bag Attributes
Microsoft Local Key set: <No Values>
localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
Microsoft CSP Name: Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider
friendlyName: 921ddddfb37214c2d5593e0c9b386a34_bc31898e-7ad7-4e24-9c39-0088bf3b937a
Key Attributes
X509v3 Key Usage: 10 
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
Some Text Here   
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
Bag Attributes
localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=example.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
More Text here 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
friendlyName: Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority  G2
subject=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Other Text here as well
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes: <Empty Attributes>
subject=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Last bit of text here 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

( removed the text of the certificates for ease of reading, and security)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
Some Text Here   
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

is an encrypted PKCS#8 private key and it should be placed in a file and the passphrase removed with:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -in <in file> -nocrypt -out private.key
```

Note that the above command will ask for the password.

This `private.key` file is pointed to by `SSLCertificateKeyFile`.

The various sections with:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Text here 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

are your certificates.  They need to be placed in files as follows:

The one below `subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=example.com` is your site certificate and should be placed in a file that is pointed to by `SSLCertificateFile`.

The last one is your issuing CA's certificate and should be placed in a file that is pointed to by `SSLCertificateChainFile`.

The remaining one (the one in between the two above) is the Root CA certificate and that should already be stored in the trust anchor store of all clients.  You don't need to do anything with that one.

Comment: So, I created my private.key following your example. I split the 3 certificates up calling them cert_1.crt, cert2.crt, & cert3.crt
    `SSLCertificateFile /var/cert_1.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/cert_3.crt`

I when restarting Apache I get the following message:
    `Certificate and private key example.com:443:0 from /var/arges86_1.crt and /var/private.key do not match`

Comment: Where does `arges86_1.crt` come into it? `SSLCertificateFile` points to `cert_1.crt` - or is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Should have been /var/cert_1.crt

Comment: You can check that the key and certificate match using OpenSSL.  For the key use: `openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in <keyfile> | md5sum` and for the certificate use: `openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in <certificate> | md5sum`.  The output of both should match.  Note that you can run those commands without piping to `md5sum` but the two outputs for comparison will be very long - comparing the md5 hash of those values just makes it a shorter task.

Comment: Ok, so it seems i'm bad @ copy & paste. I fixed that, and named them correctly and Apache now starts w/o errors. Thank you so much @garethTheRed for your help. On android devices, my website prompts saying " No Certificates found" should this be its own thread? I found a related (but unhelpful since he was using IIS) post here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005776/how-can-i-fix-the-no-certificates-found-the-app-chrome-has-requested-a-certif)

Comment: I'd do some more research (such as what do other browsers do - both desktop and mobile) and then post as another question.  It doesn't fit the title of this question.